# How can I link one drupal View field (an image) to a QuickTab?

Tags: views, 7, navigation, blocks

Im trying to link each image field of my view to a quicktab that I created. This is my view

> [image: you can see the fields of each image]

and this is how it looks

> [image]

As you see I already tried to put the url link and rewrite the stuff, I put content and nothing to the image (the part of the landing), I even tried to put it as an external link, but it never recognize it as a link.

> [image: This is the QuickTab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
What I did:

1. Create 2 different content types for each image.
2. Then I did add each one as a field.
3. Then I played with Filter criteria, adding a taxonomy term previously in my content type.

[image]

4. Then I did rewrite the results of each field (each image) to land to the page that I wanted.
5. Finally I did create the basic pages inserting in each one the Quicktabs that I needed.

And voilá! that was all :D

Thanks